# Javascript Google Apps Script Using Variables in getRange A1 Notation

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

If I use Javascript code in Google Apps Script I have following problem:
If I have the code below it works, I can copy row 3 to row 4 in the SpreadsheetApp (Google Sheets) by using this:

```
function copyrow(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var x = 3;
var y = 4;
var RangeToCopy = ss.getRange("Sheet4!3:3");
RangeToCopy.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet4!4:4"));
}
```

However, if I change the code to use variables in the `getRange` method (as below) it doesn't work. It gives me the error "Range not found (line 16, file "Code")"

```
function copyrow(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var x = 3;
var y = 4;
var RangeToCopy = ss.getRange("Sheet4!x:x");
RangeToCopy.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet4!y:y"));
}
```

How can I use variables in the `getRange` methods or variables to copy some data from one range to another?

Thank you for the help in advance

Comment: the first part of your question is really unnecessary and more confusing.
also please note which software you are using, because there are different ones on different OS.
and tell us if is there any Error or not. if there is, write your errors also (reading error logs may help so much)

Comment: You need to be specific about which language you're using - the [tag:scripting] tag is too broad to be useful.

Comment: sry, thought that it is already clear due to the heading, its javascript in google apps script...using the script for the spreadsheet app

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this:

```
function copyrow(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var x = 3;
  var y = 4;
  //var RangeToCopy = ss.getRange("Sheet4!x:x");
  var RangeToCopy = ss.getRange(Utilities.formatString('Sheet4!%s:%s',x,x));
  //RangeToCopy.copyTo(ss.getRange("Sheet4!y:y"));
  RangeToCopy.copyTo(ss.getRange(Utilities.formatString('Sheet4!%s:%s',y,y)));
}
```

You could also use this approach:

```
RangeToCopy.copyTo(ss.getRange('Sheet4!' + y + ':' + y));
```

Note: using this approach with columns like "A:A" often leads to having nulls from the bottom of your data to bottom of your page which can be a nuissance removing.  Personally, that's why I avoid it in favor of `getRange(row,column,numberofrows,numberofcols)`

Comment: Thank you, both methods work and its possible now to copy the range)